# IF/ ELSEIF / ELSE misfiring

Tags: php

```
$type = trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_GET['type'])));
$referer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];     

if ($type == "Clinical" && $referer == "al.php?zh=loadPage") {
    echo "clinical";
}
elseif ($type == "AnnualEducation" && referer == "ual.php?zh=loadPage") {
    echo "annual";
}
else {
    echo "neither";
}
```

The issue I am having is if the type is `Clinical` and `al.php?zh=loadpage` then the IF fires (which is correct) but when the type is `AnnualEducation` and `ual.php?zh=loadpage` the ELSE fires. Somehow the elseif is being skipped.

Any idea to resolve it?

Comment: In your elseif you have `referer`. Shouldn't that be `$referer`?

Comment: and `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` is a fully qualified URL when present, isn't it?

Comment: WOW... simple mistake! Thanks guys.

Comment: Have you inspected the values of `$type` and `$referer` to ensure that their values are as you expect prior to hitting your if statement?

Comment: I was missing the "$" in the referer variable in the ELSEIF statement. I will test now.

Comment: You may want to use `===` instead of `==` because `'0XAB' == '0xab'` is true

Comment: manix... good point! thank you for pointing out but the $type and $referer is generated from the server so it will always be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `elseif`

```
elseif ($type == "AnnualEducation" && referer == "ual.php?zh=loadPage") {
```

should be

```
elseif ($type == "AnnualEducation" && $referer == "ual.php?zh=loadPage") {
```

You are missing a `$` in `$referer`

Comment: Actually SO sometime makes you wait before accepting. My apology for the delay but its really SO's fault :/ lol
Answer accepted.